Windows Terminal, Command Prompt, and PowerShell cannot change directory to or start in a folder with Asian characters
I'm on Windows 10.
I have this problem where I'm unable to start the terminal (which I set up to start with Powershell), or changing directory to this folder:
D:\Scanlation\神作家・紫式部のありえない日々\Upscaled\[20220425][一般コミック][D・キッサン] 神作家・紫式部のありえない日々 1 [ZERO-SUMコミックス][UPSCALED][AVIF][DL版]
If I try to start the terminal in there, it instead starts on C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>, and if I try to use the cd command from anywhere to enter it, I get the following error:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> cd "D:\Scanlation\???·???????????\Upscaled\[20220425][??????][D·????] ???·??????????? 1 [ZERO-SUM?????][UPSCALED][AVIF][DL?]"
cd : It is not possible to find the path'D:\Scanlation\神作家・紫式部のありえない日々\Upscaled\[20220425][一般コミック][D・キッサン]
神作家・紫式部のありえない日々 1 [ZERO-SUMコミックス][UPSCALED][AVIF][DL版]' because it does not exist.
In line:1 character:1
+ cd "D:\Scanlation\神作家・紫式部のありえない日々\Upscaled\[20220425][一般コミック][D・キッサン] ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Scanlation\神...LED][AVIF][DL版]:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

However, if I try to cd to it in Git Bash (which I installed with Git), or if I set up Terminal to start with Git Bash), it works fine.
Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?
EDIT
No, it does not exceed 255 characters. Locale is Brazil. Also, I have no idea how to check the encoding, I have no idea what byte-order marks are, and that Microsoft article is basically gibberish to me. Could you please elaborate more?

Which PowerShell version?

From the path you show under CD, the characters in \Scanlation\神作家・紫式部のありえない are being rendered as Scanlation\???·???????????. Are they being copied and entered as UTF-16 BOM, UTF-16, etc.? Check encoding and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.4 "Using any Unicode encoding, except UTF7, always creates a BOM."

I would also question if the path exceeds the 255 character limit. What is the locale of the Windows installation set to? [Edit] your question instead of submitting an unformatted comment

The square brackets [ ] are special characters in PowerShell, so you can either escape those characters with backtick `, or specify the folder name as a literal path:
# escaped
cd '.\`[20220425`]`[一般コミック`]`[D・キッサン`]神作家・紫式部のありえない日々 1 `[ZERO-SUMコミックス`]`[UPSCALED`]`[AVIF`]`[DL版`]'
# literal
cd -LiteralPath '[20220425][一般コミック][D・キッサン]神作家・紫式部のありえない日々 1 [ZERO-SUMコミックス][UPSCALED][AVIF][DL版]'

Tab-completion will auto-escape those characters for you
